# How in javascript string convert in code?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have some trouble;

I want to change code
in row labels (this is parameters of chart.js)
but my labels change and i want to set this parameter

Example
From this

```
 var nData = {
                    labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
             }
```

to

```
var nData = {
                    labels: [**"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"**]
             }
```

From

```
 var nData = {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],

                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,0,220,1)",

                        data: [array[0].amount, array[1].amount, array[2].amount, array[3].amount, array[4].amount, array[5].amount, array[6].amount,array[7].amount],

                        title : "My revenue"
                    }
                ]
            };


            var opts = {
                scaleLineColor: "gray", 
            }

            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window = new Chart(ctx).Line(nData,opts);
        }
```

like this,
but this variant is not work.

```
var a="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
     var nData = {
                        labels: [eval(a)],

                        datasets: [
                            {
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,0,220,1)",

                                data: [array[0].amount, array[1].amount, array[2].amount, array[3].amount, array[4].amount, array[5].amount, array[6].amount,array[7].amount],

                                title : "My revenue"
                            }
                        ]
                    };


                    var opts = {
                        scaleLineColor: "gray", 
                    }

                    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                    window = new Chart(ctx).Line(nData,opts);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it's just:

```
nData.labels = [nData.labels.join()];
```

It's equivalent to

```
nData.labels = [nData.labels.join(',')];
```

because the default value for `join` is a comma.

A third option is to do

```
nData.labels = [nData.labels.toString()];
```

Which in this case also will return the desired result.